# How to connect AWS ELB to RDS running MS SQL?

Tags: php, sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, amazon-rds

AWS clearly states [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_PHP.rds.html) and in the [Q&A](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=584121) that one can connect to an MS SQL server using a PHP instance on the Elastic Beanstalk.

However, there seems to be no way to install the MSSQL drivers.

For example, installing `yum php-mssql` from the ELB command line, generates errors stating that the versions of the dependencies needed are too high.

Here's a classic error report:

> <sup>--> Running transaction check
>
>   ---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.3.29-1.8.amzn1 will be installed
>
>   --> Processing Conflict: php54-common-5.4.45-1.75.amzn1.x86_64 conflicts php-common < 5.4.45-1.75.amzn1
>
>   --> Processing Conflict: php54-pdo-5.4.45-1.75.amzn1.x86_64 conflicts php-pdo < 5.4.45-1.75.amzn1
>
>   --> Finished Dependency Resolution
>
>   **Error: php54-pdo conflicts with php-pdo-5.3.29-1.8.amzn1.x86_64
>
>   Error: php54-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.29-1.8.amzn1.x86_64**
>
>    You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
>
>    You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest</sup>

So how does one connect to MS-SQL with PHP on AWS ELB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to choose Amazon Linux *version 5.3*  when creating your beanstalk application.

After choosing *PHP* on the *Environment Type* screen, the next line says:

> <sup>AWS Elastic Beanstalk will create an environment running PHP 5.6 on 64bit Amazon Linux 2015.09 v2.0.8. [Change platform version](https://console.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/home?region=some-region).</sup>

Click the link [Change platform version](https://console.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/home?region=some-region) and you will be given a drop-down of possible versions.

[image: AWS PHP Linux versions]

The only version that seems to work is the last one on the list: **5.3 on 64bit Amazon Linux** (I did not try 32bit, bit it probably also works.)

Then create a *01.config* file that resides in the *.ebextensions* folder and make sure it includes:

```
packages: 
  yum:
    php-mssql: []
```

<sup>Beware: Indentation counts in this file.</sup>

You can now use code like this to connect:

```
<?php
// connect to database server
$db_conn = mssql_connect("your.rds.amazonaws.com","user","passw0rd")
   or die( "<strong>ERROR: Connection to MYSERVER failed</strong>" );

// select database - only if we want to query another database than the default one
mssql_select_db( "database1", $db_conn )
   or die( "<strong>ERROR: Selecting database failed</strong>" );

// query the database
$query_result = mssql_query( "SELECT * FROM table1", $db_conn )
   or die( "<strong>ERROR: Query failed</strong>" );
$row = mssql_fetch_array($query_result);
echo $row[0];
?>
```

Now it works as expected.

<sup>This is the result of 2 days work, shared here as this info does not seem to exist anywhere.</sup>