# How do install pdo_sqlsrv driver in elastic beanstalk to connect SQL server db instance

Tags: php, sql-server, amazon-web-services

I am trying to connect my SQL server db instance to my PHP application in elastic beanstalk.It is giving me an *error* "**driver 1 not found**". I am using following code to connect my db instance inside same environment.

```
<?php
$dbhost = $_SERVER;
$dbport = $_SERVER;
$dbname = $_SERVER;
$charset = 'utf8' ;
$dsn = "sqlsrvl:host={$dbhost};port={$dbport};dbname={$dbname};charset={$charset}";
$username = $_SERVER;
$password = $_SERVER;
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
?>
```

AWS developer guide mentions to install a driver for PDO_SQLSRV. I tried installing driver by using .ebextensions folder in my application root directory with a .config file to install the package.

```
packages: 
yum:
php56-mssql: []
```

but this result in degrading my environment health to server.

I used this links as my reference 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_PHP.rds.html
http://techqa.info/programming/question/35984661/how-to-connect-aws-elb-to-rds-running-ms-sql

```
Is there any other way to install pdo_sqlsrv driver and extension in elastic beanstalk php application ?
```

I am new to aws .Please help me to resolve this problem it would bee appreciated.

**Addition info**:
My platform: 64bit Amazon Linux 2016.09 v2.3.3 running PHP 7.0

Comment: `$dbhost = $_SERVER;` - is this your actual code? Because that isn't going to do what you think it's going to do.

Comment: This is a piece of code that i used to connect. It works well on localhost after installing the **pdo_sqlsrv** driver in php/ext folder and editing **php.ini** file with extenstion.   `extension=php_pdo_mssql.dll`. I will repeat my question. How to install pdo_sqlsrv driver and extension in elastic beanstalk php application ? .Thanks @Bytewave for showing interest to help me.

Comment: I followed this answer but it did not help.[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35984661/how-to-connect-aws-elb-to-rds-running-ms-sql/35984662)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying multiple answers, I figured out the solution for this issue.

The problem was **PHP 7.0 version**, for which I had to use package

```
commands:
  00install_mssql:
    command: yum install -y php70-mssql
```

Adding the above code in my application root directory .ebextensions/any.config file

In my case, the amazon document did not helped me because it mentions PDO_SQLSRV driver to be install but they do not support that driver instead I had to use **[PDO_DBLIB driver](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php)** below is an example of it.

```
$dbhost = 'XXXXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.amazonaws.com:1433';
$dbname = 'dbname';
$charset = 'utf8' ;
$username = 'usernam';
$password = 'password';

$pdo = new PDO("dblib:host=$dbhost;Database=$dbname", $username, $password);

$pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_CURSOR, PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL);

$tsql ="Select InvID, Number, ProfileNum, PName, InvDate, Des
       FROM dbname.dbo
       WHERE ProfileNum ='" . $client_no .  "'
       AND InvDate BETWEEN '". $inv_from_date."' AND '".$inv_to_date."'
       ORDER BY InvID";

ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);

/*  Execute the query.*/  
$stmt = $pdo->query( $tsql );

    if ( $stmt->execute() )
      { echo "Statement executed.<br>\\n";  }
    else
      {  echo "Error in statement execution.\\n";
           die( print_r(DBLib_error(), true));  }

$title = $stmt->fetchColumn(3);
print "Client Number :" . $client_no .  " <br />";
print" Client Name  &nbsp&nbsp :" . $title. ""; // Displaying Client Information
```